# Where do bitcoin transaction fees go

Tags: transaction-fees

I have 2 wallets, and was about to send bitcoins from 1 wallet to another.  I noticed that I had to pay a fee of 0.0001BTC.  Where does that fee go?

One of my wallets was created using bitcoin-qt and the other wallet was created using multibit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes to the Bitcoin miners.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees